# The number of distinct conjugates of a $p$-subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a $p$-group and $H$ be a $p$-subgroup of $G$; $H$ is not normal in $G$. Then prove that the number of distinct conjugates of $H$ in $G$ divides $|G|$. 
Notice that the conjugates may have nontrivial intersection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

The number of distinct conjugates of subgroup $H\leq G$ equals index $$[G:N_G(H)]$$ Here $N_G(H)=\{g \in G : g^{-1}Hg=H\}$ is the normalizer of $H$ in $G$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Omega$ be set of all conjugates of $H$ then $G$ act on $\Omega$ by conjugation. And since every element is a conjugate of $H$, this action is transitive.

---

**By orbit stabilizer theorem**; $$|\Omega|=|G:Stab(H)|$$

And $Stab(H)=\{g\in G| g^{-1}Hg=H\}=N_G(H)$ so we are done.

**Note:** We do not use whether $G$ is a $p$ group or not as it is true for all groups.